# 3 level dependent select - on change, trigger

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need 3 selects based by previous select. Second "trigger" in #kategoria_udalosti_hd not working, and I dont know where I doing a mistake. If is INDEX1, INDEX2 or INDEX3 in database, I want to see in select box like "selected". Because, now I have to click on select to show another select. Can anyone help me, please?

```
<select id="index_udalosti_hd" class="form_SoZ" name="index_udalosti_hd" >
   <option value="">INDEX 1</option>
   <option value="1">val 1</option>
   <option value="2">val 2</option>
   .. etc
</select>

<select id="kategoria_udalosti_hd" class="form_SoZ" name="kategoria_udalosti_hd" >
   <option value="" disabled="disabled">INDEX 2</option>
</select>

<select id="typ_udalosti_hd" class="form_SoZ" name="typ_udalosti_hd" >
   <option value="" disabled="disabled">INDEX 3</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#index_udalosti_hd').bind('change', function(){
            var index_udalosti_hd = $(this).val();
            if(index_udalosti_hd){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'url',
                    data: {kategoria_udalosti_hd: index_udalosti_hd},
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#kategoria_udalosti_hd').html(html);
                        $('#typ_udalosti_hd').html('<option value="" disabled="disabled">Vyberte INDEX 2z</option>'); 
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#kategoria_udalosti_hd').html('<option value="" disabled="disabled">Vyberte INDEX 1</option>');
                $('#typ_udalosti_hd').html('<option value="" disabled="disabled">Vyberte INDEX 1</option>'); 
            }
        });
        $('#index_udalosti_hd').trigger('change');

        $('#kategoria_udalosti_hd').bind('change',function(){
            var kategoria_udalosti_hd = $(this).val();
            console.log("kat "+ kategoria_udalosti_hd);
            if(kategoria_udalosti_hd){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'url',
                    data:{typ_udalosti_hd: kategoria_udalosti_hd},
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#typ_udalosti_hd').html(html);
                    }
                }); 
            }else{
                $('#typ_udalosti_hd').html('<option value="" disabled="disabled">Vyberte INDEX 2</option>'); 
            }
        });
        $('#kategoria_udalosti_hd').trigger('change');

    });
```

Comment: is value valid here? `url:'url',`

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you see errors in the console when you change values? Does it simply not populate the next select? Which one is the problem, the second one after the first one changes or the third one after the second one changes?

Comment: @El_Vanja I need load value #kategoria_udalosti_hd. This value is in db, but its not showing. (https://scontent.fprg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/92169084_584594219067180_6175261616926359552_n.png?_nc_cat=110&_nc_sid=b96e70&_nc_ohc=hJS8E1oIi00AX9ZLyXD&_nc_ht=scontent.fprg2-1.fna&oh=68e418ed31e367586a03aa9e987c2dd2&oe=5EB0738D)

Comment: Have you checked your developer toolbar? Any errors in console? What about the network tab, have you checked what AJAX is returning?